# Consistent 403 Error from REST API on v 1.9.3.2

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api, http-status-403

### The Setup

I've been through every post I can find on this and still no luck. I've got code for authorizing with and connecting to the REST API. In a test environment running 1.9.1.1 this all works flawlessly, in production running 1.9.3.2 it's always getting a 403.

### What I've Tried

I've been over the configuration multiple times, the roles and permissions are configured correctly, everything is the same, yet it always fails in production.

### Other Info

The company maintaining the server are sure the request is being handled by Magento, and one curious thing I have noticed is that if I omit part of the authorization header in test it'll tell me:

```
{"error":[{"code":401,"message":"oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_signature_method"}]}}
```

In production the only response I ever get back when hitting a valid URL is:

```
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":403,"message":"Access denied"}]}}
```

The only other difference is that production forces HTTPS, while in the test environment there's no valid cert and so I have to use HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through more and more with the company running the server, it appears as [though the `Authorization` header was being stripped as detailed on magentogeek.com](http://www.magentogeek.com/magento-rest-api-solution-for-400-bad-request/):

> It seems Apache was stripping the Authorization and Content-Type  header to improve security. So there was no headers given to php-fpm from FastCGI. The solution is to explicitly tell FastCGi to pass the Authorization header to php-fpm. In your fastcgi configuration file, make the following change (on Ubuntu it lies in /etc/apache2/mods-available)
>
> `FastCGIExternalServer /var/www/cgi-bin/php5.fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -idle-timeout 600 -pass-header Authorization -pass-header Content-Type`

Posting this here as I never found anything pertaining to this cause in all my searching, it was only when we knew about the missing header that the answer was easy to find.